# How to use Golang generics types in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, generics, aws-lambda

The prerequisite is Golang version 1.19.

The code is written on the assumption that requests to Lambda come from SNS and API Gateway.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type TestInterface interface {
    events.APIGatewayProxyRequest | events.SNSEvent
}

func mixHandler[T TestInterface](event T) {
    switch (interface{})(event).(type) {
    case events.SNSEvent:
        fmt.Println("SNS request")
        logStr := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", event)
        fmt.Println(logStr)
    case events.APIGatewayProxyRequest:
        fmt.Println("API Gateway request")
        logStr := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", event)
        fmt.Println(logStr)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Unknow request")
        logStr := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", event)
        fmt.Println(logStr)
        valueType := reflect.TypeOf(event)
        fmt.Println(valueType)
    }
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(mixHandler)
}
```

I thought this was OK, and when I used Execute, the following error occurred.
`cannot use generic function mixHandler without instantiation`

I know that the error is occurring because it is not instantiated as the cause.
My main question is, Is it possible to use a function that uses generics types as arguments in lambda?

As a side note, the function is executed successfully when executed with the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type TestInterface interface {
    events.APIGatewayProxyRequest | events.SNSEvent
}

func mixHandler[T TestInterface](event T) {
    switch (interface{})(event).(type) {
    case events.SNSEvent:
        fmt.Println("SNS request")
        logStr := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", event)
        fmt.Println(logStr)
    case events.APIGatewayProxyRequest:
        fmt.Println("API Gateway request")
        logStr := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", event)
        fmt.Println(logStr)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Unknow request")
        logStr := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", event)
        fmt.Println(logStr)
        valueType := reflect.TypeOf(event)
        fmt.Println(valueType)
    }
}

func main() {
    t := events.SNSEvent{}
    mixHandler(t)
}
```

Log

```
➤ go run main.go
SNS request
{Records:[]}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the use of generics is not helpful here I think.

Comment: Does this still mean that there is no way to solve this problem with Lambda at the moment?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you can solve this, but not using Go.